# azure function tool for vs2015 connection string

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have created azure function app project using azure function tool for vs2015.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/12/01/visual-studio-tools-for-azure-functions/

the project has appsettings.json file, which is being used to read application settings, which we set in application settings section on azure function.
the format is

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "",
    ------
   }
}
```

How do i add connection string in this appsettings.json file , which i have configured in azure function Connection string section

Comment: I have tried following
{
"IsEncrypted": false, 
"Values": { 
"AzureWebJobsStorage": "",
 ------
 },
"ConnectionStrings":{
"ConnectionStringName" : "Value"
}
}

I tried to access connecton string by ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionStringName"]
but no luck...

Answer (score 3):

You can just edit the appsettings.json file in a text editor to add the connection string.

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
   "Values": {
        "AzureWebJobsDashboard": "<connectionstring>",
        "AzureWebJobsStorage": "<connectionstring>",
        "MyAppsetting": "<connectionstring>",
        .... etc ...
    },
    "ConnectionStrings": {
        "DbConStr": "data source=(localdb)\\MS..." ,
        "ConnectionStringName": "data source=(localdb)\\MS..." ,
         .... etc ...
    }
}
```

The file should be in the root of your project.

Comment: can u plz write syntax how to do that ??

Comment: I am using Entity Framework DbContext inside the function

When i initialize the context i.e. 

var context = new Context();

i get the exception : 

No connection string named 'ConnectionStringName' could be found in the application config file.

Comment: Have tried to add it as: "ConnectionStringName": "<connectionstring>", to the Values?

Comment: Yes I have tried that as well,
Now what i have changed is 

{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsDashboard": "<connectionstring>",
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "<connectionstring>",
    "MyConnection": "<connectionstring>",
    .... etc ...
  },
    "ConnectionStrings": 
      {
        "ConnectionStringName": "<ConnectionString>"
       }
}

so now i am getting this error :


 The connection string 'ConnectionStringName' in the application's configuration file does not contain the required providerName attribute."

Comment: That's what i have tried and mentioned in comment....
but now i am getting error ..........
The connection string 'ConnectionStringName' in the application's configuration file does not contain the required providerName attribute."

Comment: @Peter this is how it *should* work, once the bugfix I mentioned in my answer goes through. I posted a separate answer just to make sure people see it.

Comment: What is this ConnectString used for? I'm having the same problem, but I'm  only trying to connect to an EventHub

Comment: The "ConnectionStrings" section is used to specify the connection string for connecting to external databases.

Add your azure event hub connection string in "Values" section --> Then you can read it with ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Your Connection"]

Answer (score 2):

The latest released version 0.91 of the Azure Functions CLI (which is what is used by the Visual Studio Tooling) doesn't set a the `providerName` attribute for connection strings (see https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-cli/issues/46).

The issue has been fixed in the CLI repo, but we haven't released a new version yet. If you want the fix sooner, you can build the project yourself and copy the build output to the folder `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Azure.Functions.Cli\1.0.0-beta.91`.